# Cannot remove previously installed PlugIns from Eclipse which I removed manually in Ubuntu

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu

The steps I thought I did (as far as I can remember) are the following:

First:

```
$ sudo apt-get install eclipse
```

After that I installed different PlugIns like Eclipse EGit through

> Help -> Install new Software: used the Indigo Update Site here

Following the above I purged my installation

```
$ sudo apt-get purge eclipse
$ sudo apt-get autoremove
```

And then I removed the workspace and .eclipse from /home/user

A new Installation shows the same PlugIns I installed previously in the "Install new Software" dialog which aren't there anymore (I think). It shows them as installed, but I cannot reinstall them. If I try by example install Eclipse EGit again, Eclipse tells me, that a newer version of this plugIn is already installed and that's why It will be ignored. 
If I follow

> Help -> About Eclipse Platform: click on Installation Details

I can see all of my installed PlugIns, but am not able to uninstall them. This dialog option is outgrayed (don't know how to describe it better).

I tried to run Eclipse as root through

```
$ sudo eclipse
```

but then eclipse chrashes (I think because of the missing PlugIns)

There are other Users on this OS, so I cannot clean it down from root I guess, but I am not sure about this.

My goal is to remove everything eclipse related, so I can do a clean installation. The more plain solutions didn't work for me, but I guess this can be done very easy.

Thanks in advance

EDIT:
These are the contents of /etc/eclipse.ini

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.dist.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.dist
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Xms40m
-Xmx384m
-Dorg.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins.directory=/usr/share/eclipse/dropins
```

Comment: Also, what are the contents of `eclipse.ini`? If you're using a script or shortcut to launch Eclipse, what are its contents?

Comment: In a shared installation, the default user configuration location is `<user-home-dir>/.eclipse/<product-id>_<product-version>/configuration`. The P2 configuration is stored in `<user-home-dir>/.p2`  Can you confirm that you've completely removed **both** of those directories?

Comment: At the moment I already did the deinstalltion of eclipse (3.8) from the official ubuntu repository. Additionally I followed your suggestion and installed the newest eclipse from eclipse.org. I don't have the folder .p2 at ~, but I didn't remove ~/.eclipse/org.eclipse_3.8_155965261.

Comment: Hopefully the ubuntu repository eclipse installation (3.8) and the new zip-like eclipse won't make things further complicated. I am not able to determine which file belongs to which installation, but I guess all files of the zip-like eclipse in its own folder (at the moment located under ~ because I wanted it there) aren't of much importance because this installation works. This also prevents me from deleting ~/.eclipse because I think that some of these files belong to the zip-like eclipse..

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `apt-get` to install Eclipse (some version of Eclipse that the linux distro maintainers decided is good for you), [download it directly from eclipse.org](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) and install as a user-level application. That's not a multi-user install, but I think you'll find it much easier to manage that way. Plus, you get to decide exactly which release and package of Eclipse is best for you.

Comment: But that would leave me with the broken one, doesn't it?

Comment: I followed your suggestion. Explanation in the comment of the question